# Azure API Management: How to create the Authorization or credential provider using PowerShell or Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I want to create the Authorization or credential provider in Azure API Management using PowerShell or Azure CLI. However, I don't see any options to do so. Can you suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/?view=azps-10.4.1#api-management)/[AzCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest) cmdlets for Azure API Management didn't find any cmdlet related to credential manager.

To achieve this, you can call the Azure Management REST API for [AuthorizationProvider - Create or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/authorization-provider/create-or-update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP) using the [Invoke-AzRestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-10.4.1).